# Datagrid two way binding is not working

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a datagrid, xaml is like:

```
<DataGrid HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" RenderTransformOrigin="9.75,15" Margin="19,119,0,0" Height="359" Width="1140" Name="TeamsGrid"  AutoGenerateColumns="False" >
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding sourceId}" IsReadOnly="True" Header="Kaynak takım id" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding sourceName}"  IsReadOnly="True" Header="Kaynak takım adı"/>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Button Click="btnSelectTeam">...</Button>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding BsdId}" Header="BSD Takım id" IsReadOnly="True"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding BsdName}" Header="BSD Takım adı" IsReadOnly="True"/>
        <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Binding="{Binding SaveMapping, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Header="Kaydet" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

I'm trying to bind it to a list.

```
private ObservableCollection<Team> TeamList;
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (UrlBox.Text.Contains("something"))
    {
        var mapper = new TeamMapper();
        TeamList = new ObservableCollection<Team>(mapper.MapTeams(UrlBox.Text));
    }
}
```

But when i fill the collection, data is not appearing at datagrid. So i added one line to that code:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (UrlBox.Text.Contains("something"))
    {
        var mapper = new TeamMapper();
        TeamList = new ObservableCollection<Team>(mapper.MapTeams(UrlBox.Text));
        TeamsGrid.ItemsSource = TeamList;
    }
}
```

With this code, data is appearing at datagrid but when i check a checkbox at gridview, collection is not updating.

Edit:

I changed datagrid xaml to this:

```
<DataGrid HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" RenderTransformOrigin="9.75,15" Margin="19,119,0,0" Height="359" Width="1140" Name="TeamsGrid"  AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding TeamList, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True}">
```

Comment: *I'm trying to bind it to a list*... no you're not... you're just setting the `ItemsSource` property to the collection. That's *not* binding at all. Bind it in XAML instead: `<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding TeamList}" ... />`. *collection is not updating*... does your `Team` class implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface?

Comment: @Sheridan i updated my question and added the binding. Team does not implementing INotifyPropertyChanged. Now i implemented it  and added public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged; to class. First problem is still exist, grid is not filling when i fill the list.

Answer (score 3):

The proper way to do it is to :

**First** your ViewModel must implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` Interface, using that one the `DataGrid` will be Notified in case of any changes in the collection property,

**Second** Bind the `DataGrid` `ItemSource` Property to your collection,

**Third**  Set the Window DataContext to your view model(from code using `this.DataContext=this` or from Xaml like this:

```
DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
```

the xaml:

```
<DataGrid HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" RenderTransformOrigin="9.75,15" Margin="19,119,0,0" Height="359" Width="1140"
ItemsSource="{Binding TeamList, Mode=TwoWay}" Name="TeamsGrid"  AutoGenerateColumns="False" >
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding sourceId}" IsReadOnly="True" Header="Kaynak takım id" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding sourceName}"  IsReadOnly="True" Header="Kaynak takım adı"/>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Button Click="btnSelectTeam">...</Button>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding BsdId}" Header="BSD Takım id" IsReadOnly="True"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding BsdName}" Header="BSD Takım adı" IsReadOnly="True"/>
        <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Binding="{Binding SaveMapping, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Header="Kaydet" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

and update your ViewModel/code behind :

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window,INotifyPropertyChanged
{ 

    private ObservableCollection<Team> _teamList  ;

    public ObservableCollection<Team> TeamList
    {
        get
        {
            return _teamList;
        }

        set
        {
            if (_teamList == value)
            {
                return;
            }

            _teamList = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }


    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
      if (UrlBox.Text.Contains("something"))
      {
        var mapper = new TeamMapper();
        TeamList = new ObservableCollection<Team>    (mapper.MapTeams(UrlBox.Text));
     }
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }


}
```